# Why is my output file printing the payment info backwards?

Tags: java, for-loop, filewriter, printwriter

Why does my text file print the code backward? I need it to print the loan balance decreasing from top to bottom. I didn't include the program that will call the methods, let me know if I should post that as well.

Also, if there are any other discrepancies anyone might see, let me know. Thank you!

```
           package amortizationpack;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Amortization {
    
    double loanAmount;
    double interestRate;
    double loanBalance;
    double term;
    double payment;
    int loanYears;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat number = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

    public Amortization(double userLoanAmount, int userLoanYears, double userInterestRate) {
        
        loanAmount = userLoanAmount;
        loanYears = userLoanYears;
        interestRate = userInterestRate;

        calcPayment();
        
} // constructor
    public void calcPayment() {
        term = (Math.pow((1 + interestRate / 12), (loanYears * 12)));
        payment = (loanAmount * (interestRate / 12) * term) / (term - 1);
    } // calcPayment method
    
    public int getNumberOfPayments() {
        return loanYears * 12;
    } // getNumberofPayments
    public void saveReport(String loanFile) throws IOException{
        double monthlyInterest;
        double principal;
        
        File file = new File("LoanReport.txt");
        FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileWrite);
        outputFile.println("Monthly payment: " + number.format(payment));
        outputFile.println("Month\t\t" + "Interest\t\t" + "Principal\t\t"
                + "Balance");
        outputFile.println("--------------------------------------------"
                + "-------------------");
        
    for (int m = 1; m <= getNumberOfPayments(); m++) {
    
        monthlyInterest = interestRate / 12.0 * loanBalance;
        
        if (m != getNumberOfPayments()) {
            principal = payment - monthlyInterest;
        }
        
        else {
            principal = loanBalance;
            payment = loanBalance + monthlyInterest;
        } // for last payment
        loanBalance = loanBalance - principal;
        outputFile.print(m + "\t\t" 
        + number.format(monthlyInterest) + "\t\t" +  number.format(principal) + "\t\t"
        + number.format(loanBalance) + "\n");
        
    } // for loop for writing data to text file
    outputFile.close();
    System.out.print("File Created");
        
} // saveReport
} // class
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an answer yet, maybe the way you are printing the values along the `getNumberOfPayments()` value, but correct me if I'm wrong: you are using the `loanBalance` variable before assigning it a value.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was in the comments so I don't think I could use it as an official answer, credit goes to user16320675.

Basically, I didn't initialize the loanBalance variable, so it was iterating into the negative numbers from zero, instead of decreasing from the starting balance.